When Converting excel to csv for empty cells quotes not coming
I'm trying to import excel file to csv format through power shell using this command
import-excel c:\users\xxxx\TestFile.xlsx | export-csv c:\users\xxx\CSVFile.csv -NoTypeInformation  -Encoding UTF8

It is working fine but issue is when the column value is empty for that double quotes are not coming.
Sample out put:-
"98456","Millan, Don K","Millan","Don","K",,"MD","SPECIALISTS","UROLOGY",,,,"0-99",,

Required output:-
"98456","Millan, Don K","Millan","Don","K","","MD","SPECIALISTS","UROLOGY","","","","0-99","",""

My excel input data is like below one

So is there any way to get quotes for all the empty cell when converting to csv in powershell.

Why are you using the tag for pwsh 4.0 ? are you really using that version ? if so, note that the issue you have cannot be reproduced in a newer version.

Unless you have very tetchy software reading it downstream then ,, is the most compact representation of an empty cell in Excel (which is what is present in your source data). You don't need to explicitly have a null length string in its CSV representation. BTW do you really want your numerical data imported as strings?

@MartinBrown - ymmv for other clients, but fwiw, Export-Csv and Import-Csv treat all data as strings anyway - ([pscustomobject] @{"col1"=100} | convertto-csv -> col`n"100"  (with quotes) and ("col1`n100" | convertfrom-csv).col1.gettype().FullName -> System.String. I was surprised the first time I tried that :-)

Your "missing" values imply the source data is $null for those properties:
PS> [pscustomobject] @{
    "col1"  = "val1"
    "col2" = $null
    #        ^^^^^ null value
    "col3" = "val3"
} | convertto-csv

which outputs
"col1","col2","col3"
"val1",,"val3"
#     ^^ no content

If you want an empty quoted string in the output, you need to put that value in the data:
PS> [pscustomobject] @{
    "col1" = "val1"
    "col2" = ""
    #        ^^ empty string
    "col3" = "val3"
} | convertto-csv

which then outputs:
"col1","col2","col3"
"val1","","val3"
#      ^^ empty string

So, after you've imported your data with import-excel iterate over all the results and change any $null values to "" before you call export-csv:
$data = import-excel c:\users\xxxx\TestFile.xlsx

foreach( $item in $data }
{
   foreach( $property in $item.psobject.properties )
   {
       if( $null -eq $property.Value )
       {
           $property.Value = ""
       }
   }
}

$data | export-csv c:\users\xxx\CSVFile.csv -NoTypeInformation  -Encoding UTF8

The result might not look any different if you display the property values on-screen before and after changing them, because neither $null nor ""  display any printable characters, but when you export them you'll see the desired output.

Thank you for this. It is taking some time for long files, but that is ok. It is working now
